# Function to convert first names to a specific format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, functions

I'm trying to figure out a way to show a name properly.

Let's say I have 2 variables:

- **@Firstname** = 'Marc-Oliver'
- **@Lastname** = 'Saint-Onge'

I would like to have name shown as

- `M.-O. St.Onge`
- Or at least `M.-O. Saint-Onge`

I know it's probably weird for you guys to understand this, as there are not a lot of similar situations in English, but in French this is much more familiar.

How could this be possible?

#### Update

In fact, there are many other possibilities for *first name* such as 'Pier-Luc', 'Marc-André', 'Marc-Antoine', etc. This is really familiar here in Quebec, in the French language. Forget about *last name*, I was thinking about it and I figured that it is much more specific so I won't touch it at all. I'll keep it as Saint-Onge and not St. Onge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but I'm assuming you'll be putting this into a more formalizing procedure for spitting out names.

```
DECLARE @Firstname nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Lastname nvarchar(50)

SET @Firstname =  'Marc-Oliver'
SET @Lastname = 'Saint-Onge'

SELECT @FirstName, @Lastname

IF CHARINDEX('-', @FirstName) <> 0
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Firstname, 1, 1) + '.' + 
    SUBSTRING(@Firstname, CHARINDEX('-', @Firstname), 2) + '. ' + @Lastname
ELSE
    SELECT @Firstname + ' ' + @Lastname
```

Which produces

```
Marc-Oliver     Saint-Onge
--------------------------------------------------------
M.-O. Saint-Onge
```

**Edit:**

I had never really messed around with pattern matching like this before, so it's been interesting. I believe this should work for hyphens, periods, or spaces in the first name. I tested with 'Marc Oliver', 'Marc.Oliver' and 'Marc-Oliver' all of which returned 'M.-O.' for the first name.

```
IF @Firstname LIKE '%[-. ]%'
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Firstname, 1, 1) + '.-' + 
    SUBSTRING(@Firstname, PATINDEX('%[-. ]%', @Firstname) + 1, 1) + '. ' + @Lastname
ELSE
    SELECT @Firstname + ' ' + @Lastname
```